# problem when adding a source caption to longtable and compiling with make4ht

Tags: captions, longtable, tex4ht, make4ht

The following example adds a source caption to a `longtable`. It compiles with no error using `xelatex` but crashes when `m̀ake4ht` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{%
\captionsetup{skip=0.5ex,position=b}%
\caption*{\textit{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lll}
\caption{Example.}
\\
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
\source{Test.}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The error message when compiling with `make4ht` is:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./longtable.tex  17   Misplaced \noalign.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./longtable.tex  17   Misplaced \omit.
```

and the log file shows:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\n:LT@caption: ->\o:noalign:
                             \bgroup \gHAdvance \TitleCount 1 \@ifnextchar [...
l.17 \source{Test.}
```

Is there a patch to it?

Comment: Note that in most cases one would write the source as a part of the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the purpose of the `\source` command is to add a centered text below a table. As the `\caption*` command fails in this case, we can redefine `\source` to use something that works.

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\source}[1]{%
\AddToHookNext{env/\@currenvir/after}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="source">}#1\HCode{</div>}\par}%
}
\Css{div.source{display:block;text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;font-style:italic;}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It uses the new LaTeX hook mechanism. Thanks to `\AddToHookNext`, the code is executed just once. This is important, because you don't want to insert your source to the subsequent longtables. `env/\@currenvir/after` inserts code after the current environment. Thanks to that, it will work also with `tabular` and other table environments. `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="source">}#1\HCode{</div>}\par` is just ordinary code to handle paragraphs and insert HTML code.

This is the result:

[image]